# Почему не отображаются виджеты?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Начал изучать Qt5 и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Пытаюсь по примеру создать 3 виджета (QListWidget) и скомпоновать их по вертикали, но ничего не выводит.
Вот фрагмент кода:

```
QVBoxLayout* vBox = new  QVBoxLayout(this);
vBox->setSpacing(1);
QListWidget* selectMail = new QListWidget;
QListWidget* selectEmail = new QListWidget;
QListWidget* textEmail = new QListWidget;
vBox->addWidget(selectMail);
vBox->addWidget(selectEmail);
vBox->addWidget(textEmail);
setLayout(vBox);
```

[image: Вот что получается]

Comment: Окно от какого класса наследуется? `QMainWindow`? Добавьте в вопрос полный код создания интерфейса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При использовании [QMainWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) в качестве базового класса окна контейнером для виджетов является [centralWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#centralWidget)

Порядок создания интерфейса:

1. создаете центральный виджет

```cpp
auto centralWidget = new QWidget{};
```

2. добавляете его к окну

```cpp
this->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
```

3. Добавляете нужные элементы

```cpp
auto vBox = new  QVBoxLayout();
vBox->setSpacing(1);
auto  selectMail = new QListWidget;
auto  selectEmail = new QListWidget;
auto  textEmail = new QListWidget;
vBox->addWidget(selectMail);
vBox->addWidget(selectEmail);
vBox->addWidget(textEmail);

this->centralWidget()->setLayout(vBox); // <<<
```